# AndroidAsync Socket.io ignoring server timeout settings

Tags: java, android, timeout, socket.io

We're using AndroidAsync for Socket.io and are generally extremely happy with it. But to provide a good user experience, we need it to detect network failures fairly quickly. Out of the box, it takes a minute or more. As I understand Socket.io, the timeout is set on the server and communicated to the client in the initial handshake. But changing our server heartbeat time-out doesn't seem to affect AndroidAsync at all (though the server times out faster).

What am I missing? How do I get AndroidAsync to use the new server timeouts? Or is there a way to set them on the client side?

Note: I can set the initial connection timeout using SocketIORequest.setTimeout, but that only applies to the initial connection.

Comment: Socket.io is a javascript node module, right?

Comment: Socket.io runs across lots of platforms. I think it started on node.js. We're using it on Android in Java, with the AndroidAsync implementation.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm facing the same thing, setting socket.io().timeout(1000); Seems like the default timeout is set to 75 sec.

Comment: Same problem here, found any solutions?